# Redefine perl function using typeglob doesn't work as expected

Tags: perl, typeglob

This example works fine:

```
use File::Slurp qw(read_file);
local *File::Slurp::read_file = sub {
    return 'test';
};

warn File::Slurp::read_file('/root/test.txt'); # return 'test'
```

this one too:

```
use File::Slurp qw(read_file);
local *read_file = sub {
    return 'test';
};

warn read_file('/root/test.txt');   # return 'test'
```

but if I use full name of function in typeglob it doesn't work and attempt to read file:

```
use File::Slurp qw(read_file);
local *File::Slurp::read_file = sub {
    return 'test';
};

warn read_file('/root/test.txt');
```

Could anyone explain why I can not redefine subroutine by full namespace, `File::Slurp::read_file`, and use by short name?

In case of object method, it works fine:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
local *LWP::UserAgent::get = sub {
    return HTTP::Response->new( undef, undef, undef, 'Hello world' );    
};

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
warn $ua->get()->content;
```

Answer (score 7):

Your problem is caused by how the way export works. and how Perl assigns names to values. In Perl each name is a link to a value so `sub read_line { ... }` creates an anonymous subroutine reference and assigns it to the name `&read_line`

```
use File::Slurp qw(read_file);
local *File::Slurp::read_file = sub {
    return 'test';
};
```

In your first example you are overriding `File::Slurp::read_file` and then calling `File::Slurp::read_file` so you get your version of `File::Slurp::read_file`.

```
use File::Slurp qw(read_file);
local *read_file = sub {
    return 'test';
};
```

In your second example you are overriding your imported version of `read_file` and then calling that so you get your version of `read_file`

```
use File::Slurp qw(read_file);
local *File::Slurp::read_file = sub {
    return 'test';
};
```

In your third example the following happens:

`use File::Slurp;` does a `*read_file = \&File::Slurp::read_file` at compile time, which makes `read_file` point to the existing version of `File::Slurp::read_file`. Your code then assigns `*File::Slurp::read_file` a new sub ref, however this does not change `read_file` and it still points to the sub ref that `File::Slurp::read_file` originally pointed to. You then call `read_file` which is pointing to the original imported version of `File::Slurp::read_file`

In your fourth example Perl's method resolution system means that you are calling `LWP::UserAgent::get` so this is equivalent to your first example.

Comment: Good explanation, I might just add that the "imported version of `read_file`" (the OP called it *"short name"*) is `main::read_file`, i.e. there's nothing really special about it - it's just a regular symbol table entry too, in the default `package main`.

Comment: I thought about that but decided that there was nothing in the examples to show if they where in the main:: package or in another package, so I wrote it without showing the package the symbol was imported into

Comment: True. I just didn't want to leave the impression that there's something particularly  "magic" about importing or about "short names" (stuff in the default/current package), hence my comment.

Comment: Fair enough :-)

Answer (score 2):

When a sub is exported its reference is written to the caller's symbol table.  Then after the sub is redefined in the module the unqualified name in the caller still refers to the "old" one, that was Exported, and not the redefined one.

One clear fix is to explicitly alias the (unqualified) name in the calling package

```
*func = *{ Module::func } = sub { ... };
```

Then wrap this in a subroutine, from which all wanted namespaces can be taken care of

```
sub redefine_sub {
    my ($fqn, $code) = @_;

    no warnings 'redefine';  # these pragmas are lexical, and
    no strict 'refs';        # so stay scoped to this sub only

    *{ $fqn } = $code;

    # Redefine in caller
    my ($name) = $fqn =~ /.*::(.*)/;
    my $to_caller = caller() . '::' . $name;
    *{ $to_caller } = $code;
}
```

In the caller

```
use Module qw(func);

redefine_sub('Module::func', sub { ... });
```

---

(*Original attempts, that didn't work well, have been removed*)

Comment: Does this work for you if you replace `Cwd` with `File::Slurp`? Strangely, I cannot get it to work with `File::Slurp`..

Comment: @HåkonHægland You are right, it doesn't -- thank you. It's much too late here so I'm removing this for now.

Comment: @HåkonHægland Edited to address that, thank you.  I cannot see what in these modules makes that difference, and I find some more subtle behavior which I don't get. So the only fix I see is to explicitly set names in all needed namespaces.

Comment: @PaulSerikov Edited, and added a possibly reasonable way to do what you want